# Delete the oldest file from the files in the folder and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
setlocal
set Folder=C:\test\
set FileMask=*.*
set OldestFile=

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:d "%Folder%\%FileMask%" 2^>NUL') do (
    set OldestFile=%%a
    goto Break
)
:Break

if "%OldestFile%"=="" (
    echo No files found in '%Folder%' matching '%FileMask%'!
) else (
    echo del "%Folder%\%OldestFile%"
)

pause
```

Here I delete the oldest file (the file in the folder or the directory in the folder). How to delete the oldest file from the files in the folder and subfolders? It is necessary that the subfolders be checked.

Comment: at the first glance, this would be quite difficult in batch, because dir /od would sort the files folder by folder. But this link shows you a trick, how to sort over subfolders. Should be easy to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=C:\test\"
    set "fileMask=*.*"

    set "oldestFile="
    for %%f in ("%folder%\.") do for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%%~ff" "%%~ff" %fileMask% /njh /njs /nc /ns /l /is /ndl /ts /s
        ^| 2^>nul sort 
        ^| find ":"
    ') do set "oldestFile=%%b" & goto :done

    :done
    echo "%oldestFile%"
```

This uses `robocopy` to list `/l` the files with time stamp in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss` format, sort the list so the oldest file is the first and once the information of the first file has been retrieved, show it.